# in php i need one line if condition for time compare

Tags: php

i have to value

```
 $mo=strtotime($input_array['MondayOpen']);
 $mc=strtotime($input_array['MondayClose']);
```

now i need a if condition to display an error on below conditions

1. if one of them($mo or $mc) are empty, null or blank.
2. if close time($mc) is less than open time($mo)

means if both are empty(null) or $mc>$mo then go further

please suggest optimized one line if condition for this

i know it seems very basic question, but i m facing problem when both are null
either i was using simple

```
if(($mo==NULL && $mc!=NULL) || ( $mo>=$mc && ($mo!=NULL && $mc!=NULL))  )
```

Comment: Oh come on. How do you want to learn the language this way? See the manual: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php Why not try to build something, and put it up here for scrutiny / optimization.

Comment: You don't need a one liner, you need to learn to program. Sorry to be blunt, but that's what it is.

Comment: What the hell, we just answered this for you not even 4 hours ago?

Comment: no sir??
actuallay i m  getting confused on each level although i have one year experience on PHP,.. but i really facing this kind of problem, so where do i ask?
sorry for asking so basic question, but i m not getting the required result then i post here...

Comment: You will always get an answer on SO, but you really need to learn this for yourself. Otherwise, it'll take another year to get the control structures. Check out the manual I link to, there are plenty of examples there.

Comment: Sometimes examples that solve real problems are a good way to see logical concepts illustrated. I think it's highly unfair to penalize the Asker so drastically for requesting help in this case. Those of us who are experienced see this as a simple problem, but it can take time to train the brain to think this way.

Quit being jerks.

Comment: @Pekka...no body gives right answer still, and you were saying that i asked very basic question,
please sir go through my question and post the answer, i know , for u, this is very tiny task, but for me, it's very urgent

Comment: @I like PHP, I added my take on this. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in php, strotime will return a integer or false. Checking for null in this case will never bear fruit, but otherwise...

```
if((!$mo xor !$mc) || ($mc && $mc<=$mo)){
  print('error');
}else{
 print('no_error');
}
```

oops, edited for correctness. I transposed $mc and $mo. XOR should be correct though.

Comment: Still display Error when both fields have no value...please first u check on ur side

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that 0, null, and blank all mean completely different things here. As indicated previously, strtotime will never return NULL. However, **0** is a valid unix timestamp, whereas **false** means that the strtotime function was unable to process the value provided.

Also, you've requested that a single-line solution; however, in my opinion, it is much better in this case to write out each condition and display a different error message for each condition. That way, the user knows what actually went wrong. Perhaps this is a better way:

```
// Only check for errors if we have at least one value set
if (!empty($input['MondayOpen']) || !empty($input['MondayClosed']) {
    $mo = strtotime($input['MondayOpen']);
    $mc = strtotime($input['MondayClosed']);

    $invalid = false;
    if (false === $mo) {
        echo "Invalid Opening Time\n";
        $invalid = true;
    }

    if (false === $mc) {
        echo "Invalid Closing Time\n";
        $invalid = true;
    }

    if (!$invalid && $mc <= $mo) {
        echo "Closing time must be After Opening Time\n";
        $invalid = true;
    }

    if ($invalid) {
        exit();  // Or handle errors more gracefully
    }
}

// Do something useful
```

Comment: very expressive answer....thank you sir. i was really scared when so many people behave so rudely when i post so basic question..
actaully i was puzzled after converting into strtotime ans then comparing

Comment: it disply invalid opening time if we remain both field blank

Comment: this can't be right though?? he wanted to continue (not give an error) if BOTH were false!

Comment: Also, although 0 is a valid unix timestamp and it's important to illustrate the weakly typed pitfall, is it really necessary to check for it here?

Comment: @Mike Sherov  yes sir it is necessary to check....
is there any other method to check.. bcoz after this validation if everything is fine then i apply `date()` on `$mo` and `$mt` , and if there is 0 in field then date() convert it to some value. that's y i need to check these all conditions

Comment: no, what I mean is that you're not going to pass a VALID 0. You don't need === unless you plan on checking for VALID 0's.

Comment: I've modified my answer to offer a more robust solution, since you were both complaining. ;)

Comment: Mike, I understand your point, but I refuse to offer a solution that makes lazy assumptions about user input. There's nothing in the Question that demands validation about the valid date range; if there were, I would treat that as a separate validation criteria. In practice, I myself have made such assumptions, but I prefer to avoid it when it's as convenient as adding an extra '='. :)

Comment: Final Note to the Asker:
All of the changes I made in my most recent edit really should be pretty straightforward to figure out just by thinking through it. As I said before, I'm willing to help you get in the mode, but I agree with the general sentiment that we really shouldn't have to write all your code for you! :) Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

All right. How about this.

It checks whether $mo and $mc are valid dates using `is_numeric`. Any NULL or false values will be caught by that.
I haven't tested it but it should work.

I spread it into a huge block of code. In the beginning, when learning the language, this is the best way to make sense out of the code. It is not the most elegant, nor by far the shortest solution. Later, you can shorten it by removing whitespace, or by introducing `or` and stuff.

I'm not 100% sure about the number comparison part, and I don't have the time to check it right now. You'll have to try out whether it works.

You need to decide how you want to handle errors and insert the code to where my comments are. A simple `echo` might already do.

```
// If $mo or $mc are false, show error. 
// Else, proceed to checking whether $mo is larger
// than $mc.

if ((!is_numeric($mo)) and (is_numeric($mc)))
 {
   // Error: $mo is either NULL, or false, or something else, but not a number.
   // While $mc IS a number.
 }
elseif ((!is_numeric($mc)) and (is_numeric($mo)))
 {
   // Error: $mc is either NULL, or false, or something else, but not a number.
   // While $mo IS a number. 
 }
else
 {

   if (($mc <= $mo) and ((is_numeric($mc) or (is_numeric($mo)))))
    {
       // Error: closing time is before opening time.
    }
    else
     {
       // Success!!

      }

 }
```

Comment: @Pekka, I said i need one line if condition, is there not possible to make single line condtion using && || or ? : , 

it will display error when $mo and $ mc both are NULL or false, where i asked  when both are blank then show no error

Comment: @I like PHP, why on earth do you need a single line statement when you're only learning the language? And it should do exactly as you say in your question: If $mo *or* $mc are null, you will get an error. When both are `0`, then show no error but silently adjust. If you mean blank instead of 0, replace `0` by `''`.

Comment: @Pekka ... I SAID when both are null/blank/false, then it doesn't show any error. does strtotime() ever return `0`? i request you sir,please read my question again that on which condition i need to display errors(only 2 condtions)..
i heard that one if execute more fast than if inside if takes time, thats why i asked for one line code, if i m wrong then it will be fine if you code runs perfectly.
thank you...
i don't know why people give negative point on this question

Comment: @I Like PHP, forget about speed optimization in `if` statements. They are totally useless and unnecessary. You need to work with clean, readable code. Now for the second part, I admit I misread your question. I'm editing my answer, hang on.

Comment: Oh and by the way, `strtotime()` will very well return `0` for January 1st, 1970, 0:00 UTC.

Comment: Oh and by the way, there is syntax error in 
`if (($mc <= $mo) and ((is_numeric($mc) or (is_numeric($mo)))`

there would be two more paranthesis  in last
`if (($mc <= $mo) and ((is_numeric($mc) or (is_numeric($mo)))))`

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, forget about optimizing for speed in these things. Optimization becomes really important when doing a lot of database operations or dealing with large amounts of data. A clean code structure is way more important than 3 milliseconds saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
print ((empty($mo) && empty($mc)) || ($mc > $mo)) ? 'case_true_message' : 'case_false_message';
```

But you should also check the manual :) - for basic control structures

Comment: its does't display error when only $mc is full but $mo is empty